# How can I get my div inside my li element to appear first with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my div to appear on it's own line and force the li to the next line.  I can't change the html or reorganize the elements.  It needs to be a css only solution.

Here is an example:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/129rgqr7/

The current output looks like this:

```
Racquet Sports - Tennis
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Racquet Sports
Tennis
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if the site went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.) Also, some people are behind corporate firewalls that forbid the use of code sharing websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleared the answer to make it more readable:

```
li {display:flex;flex-direction:column;list-style-type:none;}
li div {order:1;} 
li span {order:2;}
```

And here's the Jsfiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/6puvsmn8/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if the site went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.) Also, some people are behind corporate firewalls that forbid the use of code sharing websites.

Comment: Unfortunately the output does not match my output.  "Racquet Sports" needs to be first.

Comment: Hey Jack! I have updated the answer to include a third solution that allows you to sort the items as you wish!

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the techniques described in [this article](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/) which also allows you to reorder the elements. Easiest with best browser support is perhaps:

```
li {
  display: table;
}

#group {
  display: table-header-group;
}
```